# layout_centerHorizontal is not centering

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout, and inside it i place 3 items, 2 imageviews and one scrollview.
My layout is like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/logosLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:gravity="center">
                    
        <!-- An image will be placed here -->

    </RelativeLayout>
    
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#33ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/up" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="32dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/hotelBtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/hotelBtnDesc"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hotelBtnDescTxtVw"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/hotelBtnDesc"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                    <!-- more scrollview items -->
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
        
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:src="@drawable/down" />
        
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above code produces the view shown here:

[image: above code executed]

You may note that the arrows are not aligned in the center, but are slightly moved to the right. Why is that, and how can I fix it ? Note that i have already used android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" to my imageviews.

Thank you in advance

Comment: remove         android:gravity="center"  from relative_layout

and use layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Comment: check my answer it will solve your problem

Comment: @BBExpert this didn;t worked for me, i had to add margins to my scroll view equal to my Relative layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its problem with your

```
android:layout_margin="8dp"
```

remove it from both scrollview and imageView

and pass it to `RelativeLayout` direct.

or add

```
android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
```

in your `RelativeLayout`.

and pass

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

to your scrollview

Comment: Well that almost worked. I had to add layout_marginLeft and layout_marginRight on the ScrollView at 16dp. Since my rep is lower that 100 i can't self answer right now, but i will to show my final layout. +1 from me!

Comment: for that i edited my ans 
and you can accept it i it works for you

Comment: The correct answer is to add `android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"`,            `android:layout_marginTop="8dp"`, 
`android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"` and 
`android:layout_marginRight="16dp"`` at ScrollView

Comment: you relativelayout is having android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" android:layout_marginRight="16dp"` already and my asnwer is saying add 
android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"

Comment: Well, this will send the images of the scrollview completly at the left having no margins ...

Comment: pass   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
to the scrollview too

Comment: Yes! that's a nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `android:layout_weight="1"` from your **RelativeLayout** and see if it works.

---

In your LinearLayout, the attribute `android:orientation="horizontal"` causing your display to be aligned horizontaly. Therefore your RelativeLayout is in center but since its shared with another layout thats why you cant note the difference. If you completely remove the first RelativeLayout (the one with id *logosLayout*) then i hope you'll see the second layout in center.

So, first you need to define the hierarchy of layout you require and then adjust your views accordingly.

Comment: After your update, seems like your RelativeLayout is also even inside some other layout. Paste your entire xml so we'll have a better picture of problem

Comment: I have added the whole layout now

Comment: My problem was in the arrows of the second relative layout. I didn't want to center the relative layout itself at the screen. Anyway, my problem is solved, i will update the thread!

Answer (score 0):

they are aligned to the center if you put the marginRight into consideration, try adding `android:layout_margin="8dp"` to the arrows.

Answer (score 0):

u need to set image view that is under the Relative layout set this image view width fill parent.

Answer (score 0):

It  seems problem with your android:layout_margin="8dp" for your scrollview only and pass it to RelativeLayout direct but instead of using margin use padding = "8dp".